# Why are session Ids in my table changing to 0?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a form for submitting students' scores which is supposed to capture the session id (session ids are used to to show the session that a school is currently on e.g 2018/2019 session, 2019/2020 session...)

[session table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGTPb.jpg)

In the scores table in the database, the session id is automatically captured and inserted. Currently, the session id is 14.

[session id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyK0M.jpg)

However, for reasons unknown 0s are inserted instead of 14. This is causing so many issues

1. In the add scores form, scores values are only repopulated if the session id is 14. Now, since it shows 0, the value boxes remain 0
2. Also I believe it causes duplicate issues. During edits in the form, all scores of students are duplicated.

***Controller***

```
function assigngradeAction() 
{


            for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post('number')); $i++)
                {

                    $data[]=array(
                         'section_id' => $this->input->post('section_id'),
                        'subject_id' => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
                        'class_id' => $this->input->post('class_id')[$i],
                        'student_id' => $this->input->post('student_id')[$i],
                        'session_id' => $this->input->post('session_id'),
                        'ca1' => $this->input->post('ca1')[$i],
                        'ca2' => $this->input->post('ca2')[$i],
                        'ca3' => $this->input->post('ca3')[$i],
                        'ca4' => $this->input->post('ca4')[$i],
                        'project' => $this->input->post('project')[$i],
                        'affective' => $this->input->post('affective')[$i],
                        'psychomotor' => $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i],
                        'exam'=> $this->input->post('exam')[$i],
                        'tot_score'=> $this->input->post('ca1')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca2')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca3')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca4')[$i] + $this->input->post('project')[$i] + $this->input->post('affective')[$i] + $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i] + $this->input->post('exam')[$i],
                    );

                }




                 $inserted = $this->primary_model->add1($data);
                 if($inserted > 0)
                 {
                     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">Grade Added successfully</div>');
                     //Echo back success json
                     redirect('admin/primary/index');
                  }           

    }
```

***model***

```
public function add1($data)
    {

        // for each record insert
        foreach($data as $studentScore){
            // get score
            $subjectId = $studentScore['subject_id'];
            $classId = $studentScore['class_id'];
            $sessionId = $studentScore['session_id'];
            $sectionId = $studentScore['section_id'];
            $studentId = $studentScore['student_id'];
            $score = $this->get_student_score($subjectId,$sessionId,$sectionId,$classId,$studentId); 
            $studentScore['modified_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            if(empty($score->id)){
                $this->db->insert('scores_primary', $studentScore);
            }else{
                $this->db->where('id', $score->id);
                $this->db->update('scores_primary', $studentScore);
            }
           // var_dump($studentScore, "\n >>>>>>>>", $score);

        }
    //   $this->db->insert_batch('scores_primary', $data);
    //   var_dump($this->db->error(), $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] );
    //   $str = $this->db->last_query();

    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($str);
       return true; 
    }
```

***view***

```
<?php }elseif($class_id >= 15 && $class_id <= 17){ ?>
                            <form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/primary/assigngradeAction') ?>" method="POST" id="formSubjectTeacher">
                               <?php echo $this->customlib->getCSRF(); ?>
                               <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="class" value="<?php echo $class_id; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="subject_id" value="<?php echo $subject_id; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">

                                        <h4><strong><?php echo $session_name; ?></strong></h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <hr>

                                <?php foreach($students as $student){ ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Student Name</label>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="number[]"  value="">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="section_id"  value="<?php echo $section_id; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="session_id"  value="<?php echo $student->session_id; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]"  value="<?php echo $student->student_id; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="class_id[]" value="<?php echo $class_id; ?>">
                                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $CI->GetStudentNameWithID($student->student_id); ?>" class="form-control "  readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                            <label>ca1 </label>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<?php echo $sessionID; ?>">
                                            <input type="number" name="ca1[]" min="0" max="10" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo $student->scores? $student->scores->ca1: 0; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1" id="t2">
                                            <label>ca2</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="ca2[]" min="0" max="10" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo $student->scores? $student->scores->ca2: 0; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1" id="assg">
                                            <label>ca3</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="ca3[]" min="0" max="10" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo $student->scores? $student->scores->ca3: 0; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1" id="exam">
                                            <label>Exam</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="exam[]" min="0" max="70" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo $student->scores? $student->scores->exam: 0; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                                            <label>Total</label>
                                            <output class="result"></output>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                              <?php } ?>
```

Comment: do you have id set with primary key and auto-increment?

Comment: @Vickel yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `view` in `form` you have two `input fields` named `session_id` ↓↓

1. `<input type="hidden" name="session_id"  value="<?php echo $student->session_id; ?>">`
2. `<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<?php echo $sessionID; ?>">`

> Duplicate fields can cause issues, check which one has the correct
>   value in it and discard the other one. If both of the fields have
>   wrong values then check where the values are being initialized and so
>   on. This is how you debug in PHP.